# Can I change the primary key setting from master detail form creator?

Tags: oracle-apex

I've created a master detail form in Oracle ApEx. In the form creator I was asked to provide primary key for the detail section. I didn't realize I should have provided rowid instead of my real primary key, which is two-piece complex and apparently ApEx have problems with the second part of the key. It doesn't allow me to insert row because of character to number conversion error. When I created the same form and provided rowid in the detail section, the problem was gone.
Anyway, the problem is I realized that much too late, I put a lot of work into that form and I have not much time to repeat that. Is there any chance to change that setting for rowid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was given an adivice that resolved my problem. I also want to notice, that my detail section was an Interactive Grid. I added hidden column to my detail section. Source settings: Type: database column, Database Column: ROWID, Data Type: ROWID, Primary Key: Yes. Then I set in Source section for the columns that were parts of my real primary key: Primary Key: No